# Lidar and Opengeo suite

Tags: postgresql, database, boundless-suite, lidar

Opengeo suite has provided a tutorial on how to manage LiDAR data using postgresql. I was trying to follow the tutorial in this [link](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-lidar/).

I am new to Linux and using Ubuntu 12.04. I have successfully installed Opengeo suite 4.1. I started off with the tutorial smoothly, installed point cloud extension and pdal and downloaded the example data. I only got stuck at the section "Loading LiDAR into the database". In this section, I followed the tutorial and implemented following codes successfully:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION pointcloud;
CREATE EXTENSION pointcloud_postgis;
```

And also the following pdal commands run smoothly:

```
pdal info --input 20090429_42122c8225_ld_p23.laz --schema
pdal info --input 20090429_42122c8225_ld_p23.laz --metadata --xml
```

Now I faced the issue while implementing the following command:

```
pdal pipeline laz2pg.xml
```

From the terminal I got the error:

> mzaman@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ pdal pipeline laz2pg.xml
>   Caught PDAL exception: unable to connect to database

This is to mention that, I have created a database in Postgresql called 'LiDAR' using pgAdmin. I kept another terminal open and run the following command using users 'postgres' and 'mzaman'.

```
mzaman@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo -u mzaman psql LiDAR
```

psql (9.3.4)
Type "help" for help.
LiDAR=#

I also tried with the user 'postgres',

```
entermzaman@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ sudo -u postgres psql LiDAR
```

But the first terminal where I run pdal command, still shows the error:

> Caught PDAL exception: unable to connect to database.

My question is, how to bypass this error?

Comment: You need to do it as postgres user.

Answer (score 3):

Great to find you here.

Have you edited the laz2pg.xml to point to your DB? You mentioned you created a database and named it "LiDAR" while the tutorial named the database "lidar". In linux world I believe "LiDAR" != "lidar".

```
<Option name="connection">dbname='lidar' user='postgres'</Option>
```

Try changing that line to:

```
<Option name="connection">dbname='LiDAR' user='postgres'</Option>
```

Cheers!